# $ rostopic list ERROR: Unable to communicate with master!

Tags: ros-kinetic, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to calibrate a Logitic 920 HD 1080p camera in Ubuntu 16.04. I have installed ros kinetik. I am not sure if this tutorial is the correct link but I get this error:

http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/StereoCalibration

```
mona@Mona:~$ rosdep install camera_calibration
#All required rosdeps installed successfully
mona@Mona:~$ rosmake camera_calibration
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['camera_calibration']                      
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/mona/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20180802-101208
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['camera_calibration'] to:
['camera_calibration']     
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> catkin [ make ]                                        
(...)

[rosmake-5] Finished <<< image_geometry ROS_NOBUILD in package image_geometry
 No Makefile in package image_geometry
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> camera_calibration [ make ]                            
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< camera_calibration ROS_NOBUILD in package camera_calibration
 No Makefile in package camera_calibration
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 45 packages with 0 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/mona/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20180802-101208              
mona@Mona:~$ rostopic list
ERROR: Unable to communicate with master!
mona@Mona:~$
```

if the tutorial is the correct one for this camera, how should I fix this error, if the tutorial is wrong, please link me to the correct tutorial.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299445/$-rostopic-list-error:-unable-to-communicate-with-master!/) by [lamiastella](https://answers.ros.org/users/23430/lamiastella/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-08-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-08-02**:
I think you have missed a step in the tutorial:

> Make sure that your stereo camera is publishing left and right images over ROS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your error has nothing to do with the camera package. The command you have problems with ('rostopic list') does not depend on your build process or the camera type you are running.

The tutorial assumes that you have worked through the [Beginner Level Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) in which you can learn how to start a roscore (and the corresponding environment variables).

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2018-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3